# Understanding Object.keys in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a following object:

```
var sample =
{
    count: {
        '20-01-2015/17': {
            'a': 553056,
            'b': 622123
        },
        '20-01-2015/18': {
            'a': 519008,
            'b': 610474
        }
    }
}
```

I want to find all the keys for `count` property. Also, all the keys for `20-01-2015/17` property also.

```
var times = Object.keys(sample.count);
console.log(times);
var time = '20-01-2015/17'

//This works
var props = Object.keys(sample.count[time]);
console.log(props);

//But this doesn't work. I am not able to understand that.
props = Object.keys(sample.count.time);
console(props)
```

I didn't understand why the first approach is working, but not the second one.

Comment: the last one try to access a property `time` on the object `count`, (not the value of time as the property name)

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys()` is used to ENUMERATE all properties that have their `Enumerable` flag turned on in the object descriptor including functions, for example, if you do this `Objects.keys(Array.prototype)` it will print all the functions defined on the prototype property of the `Array` which is shared by all `Array` objects.